# Matching dictionary keys to worksheet cell values

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, for-loop

I have not yet found any questions related to this topic, hence my question below.

I'm working with a dictionary, which have keys and items like below.

```
Keys:  30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 39
Items: 21 51 31 64 65 32 29 74 61
```

I also have some values written to the worksheet:

```
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
```

My goal is to resize the dictionary, and write the Items contained within it to the cell below the cell matching the dictionary key.

So far I've only been able to write the dictionary to a given place in the worksheet ws:

```
ws.Range("C28").Resize(1, dict.Count).Value2 = dict.Keys
ws.Range("C29").Resize(1, dict.Count).Value2 = dict.Items
```

I've tried the following code, but this is only a start. Of course, this is not where I'm going but it's all I can think of. Any help or points would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
Dim key As Variant
Dim cell As Range

With ws
For Each cell In .Range("D10:S10")
    If dict.Exists(cell.Value) Then
        cell.Offset(2, 0).Value = dict.Items
    End If
Next

For Each key In dict
    With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .Value = key
        .Offset(, 2) = dict(key)
    End With
Next
```

End With

Sample from worksheet result:
[image]

Code update after comments (not yet finished for the specific problem, but a proof of concept. It is under development with comments.)

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")   ' <- change the sheet name
    Dim oDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim iRow As Long: iRow = oWS.Cells(oWS.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row                                      ' <- iRow and be set dynamically
    Dim oCell As Range
    
    oDict.Add 30, 70
    oDict.Add 31, 71
    oDict.Add 32, 72
    oDict.Add 33, 73
    oDict.Add 34, 74
    oDict.Add 35, 75
    oDict.Add 36, 76
    oDict.Add 37, 77
    oDict.Add 38, 78
    oDict.Add 39, 79
    oDict.Add 40, 80
    oDict.Add 42, 82
    
    With oWS
        
        For Each oCell In .Range("A1:P1")
        
            If oDict.Exists(oCell.Value) Then
                iRow = iRow + 1
                '.Cells(1, iRow).Value = oCell.Value
                .Cells(2, iRow).Value = oDict.Item(oCell.Value)
            End If
        
        Next
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you want data to look like on the sheet?

Comment: Added screenshot.. :-)

Comment: So looking at your screen print, column 1 has the `dict(key)` and column 2 `dict.items`? (obviously ignoring the first 2 rows)

Comment: Yes, my mistake. The two first rows are from another query, which works just fine. Column1 is dict.Keys and column 3 is dict.Items. As you said, ignoring the two first rows. However, the first row is what I would like to match with dict.Keys.

Comment: So you only want the details from `dict` if key matches one of the values in first row?

Comment: Correct. I wish to write it to the column corresponding with the value in the first row.

Answer (score 1):

This might be over simplifying the issue but if i understand your requirements correctly, this should work

```
Sub SetDictValues()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Dim oDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim iRow As Long: iRow = oWS.Cells(oWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rKeys As Range: Set rKeys = oWS.Range("A2:A" & iRow)
    Dim rUpdateRng As Range
    Dim oCell As Range
    
    oDict.Add 30, 70
    oDict.Add 31, 71
    oDict.Add 32, 72
    oDict.Add 33, 73
    oDict.Add 34, 74
    oDict.Add 35, 75
    oDict.Add 36, 76
    oDict.Add 37, 77
    oDict.Add 38, 78
    oDict.Add 39, 79
    oDict.Add 40, 80
    
    With oWS
        
        For Each oCell In .Range("A1:K1")
        
            If oDict.Exists(oCell.Value) Then
                
                Set rUpdateRng = rKeys.Find(oCell.Value)
                If Not rUpdateRng Is Nothing Then
                    rUpdateRng.Offset(, 2).Value = oDict.Item(oCell.Value)
                End If
            End If
        
        Next
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not work straight off the back, but I did a few minor changes and it looks like it's working. I'll post the code that did the trick when it's cleaned up. :-) Thanks for your help!

Comment: I rewrote the code a bit as mentioned, but it still does not quite live up to the task at hand. I swapped (iRow,1) to (1, iRow) to make it transpose to columns as I wanted. However, I do nit want to replace the values in the top rows - I wish to keep them, and if not dict.Exists, then goto the next match. Aka., skip the "matchless" and write only where a match is found

Comment: Look at the change i;ve made on `Dim iRow As Long: iRow =...` row. That should help. Also, `iRow` is the row number and not the column number. By you swapping the cell to `(1, iRow)`, you are telling the code to put the value in the first row and whatever the value of `iRow` is as column number. When you say it does not work, what is it that dosn't work?

Comment: We're getting closer now. However, if you add oDic.Add 42, 82 (e.g) it will still write the value next to the last cell, and not underneath the corresponding oCell.Value. Thus, the answer will not be correct.

Comment: Can you add the updated code in your question so that i can see what are the changes

Comment: Added the sub I modified from you answer.

Comment: Edited code does not write values to the worksheet, sadly.

Comment: It's working for me. Please ensure that some or all of the values in top row exist in your dictionary and in column 1

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you describe:

```
'...
For Each cell In .Range("D10:S10").Cells
    if dict.Exists(cell.value) Then
        cell.Offset(2, 0).value = dict(cell.Value)
    end if
Next
'...
```

Comment: Hi, this is not working as intended. This prints keys and values down (rows) with an 2 column offset. I wish to print only the items, transposed to match the cell.Value. Sorry if I was not clear in my post.

Comment: I still can't figure out what it is you want to do - where do the 270/280 values come from?  You don't show column/row headers in your screenshot so that makes it difficult to match the code to the sheet.

Comment: They are just static values, and should be ignored. They are part of something else, and does not have anything to do with this exact question. Screenshot are explained and asked for through comments. I’ve posted the final code that worked, so go ahead and test it :-) A new issue arose though, so feel free to review. Commented.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, and great help from @Zac, I've gotten to an answer to my problem:

The final code

```
Sub SetDictValues()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim oDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim rKeys As Range
    Dim rUpdateRng As Range
    Dim oCell As Range
    
    iRow = oWS.Cells(oWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rKeys = oWS.Range("A1:A" & iRow)
    
    oDict.Add 30, 70
    oDict.Add 31, 71
    oDict.Add 32, 72
    oDict.Add 33, 73
    oDict.Add 34, 74
    oDict.Add 35, 75
    oDict.Add 36, 76
    oDict.Add 37, 77
    oDict.Add 38, 78
    oDict.Add 39, 79
    oDict.Add 40, 80
    oDict.Add 42, 81
    
    With oWS
        
        For Each oCell In .Range("A1:P1")
        
            If oDict.Exists(oCell.Value) Then
                
                Set rUpdateRng = rKeys.Find(oCell.Value)
                If Not rUpdateRng Is Nothing Then
                    rUpdateRng.Offset(1, 0).Value = oDict.Item(oCell.Value)
                End If
            End If
        
        Next
        
    End With

End Sub
```

I changed`rUpdateRng.Offset(, 2).Value to rUpdateRng.Offset(1, 0).Value` and `Set rKeys = oWS.Range("A2:A" & iRow)` to `Set rKeys = oWS.Range("A1:A" & iRow)` to avoid overwriting key values.

Comment: I ran into a new problem here. While this code works 100 % for the task at hand, if one removes "oDict.Add", change the name to SetDictValues(oDict as dictionary), it will yield blank results. I know for a fact the dictionary from previous sub is populated, as I'm printing it to the worksheet. Why does this code not work with a dictionary as input? Obviously deleting Dim oDict As New Scripting.Dictionary.

Comment: Should work fine with those changes, so there's something else going on.

Comment: I will post the full code later on. Problem in short: Code works (below answerpost), but once I implement another dictionary it doesn’t get populated, although I know for a fact the dict is full of data through debug. Full code will be edited in the code..